# What is necessary to allow Jest, using ts-jest and webpack, to recognize and parse module aliases?

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a `.ts` file I want to test.

**frontend/game/index.ts**

```
import App from '@/views/app';
let app = new App({
  el: "#app",
});
export default app;
```

The file I'd like to import in `index.ts` is 
`frontend/game/views/app.vue` . Webpack-dev-server, eslint, and (I assume) ts-loader are all capable of resolving the module import with the `@` alias, as there are no errors in my build or develop steps.

However, when I run jest, I get the following error:

```
   TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
    frontend/game/index.ts:1:17 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/views/app'.

    1 import App from '@/views/app';
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It refers to the first line of my `file.spec.js` file:

**frontend/tests/game/models/file.spec.js**

```
import App from '@/views/app';
```

I have followed the recommendations of the [typescript module resolution documentation,](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) as well as [articles specifically about setting up webpack/typescript/jest projects.](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/type-safe-es2015-module-import-path-aliasing-with-webpack-typescript-and-jest-fe461347e010)

Their recommendations generally revolve around setting up the alias in 3 places:

1. webpack config, under `resolve.alias`. Mine:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './frontend/game/index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'staticfiles')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.scss', '.sass'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/game/')
    }
  },
```

2. Jest Config, under `moduleNameMapper`. Mine:

**package.json** (where my jest config is located)

```
 "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "vue",
      "ts"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "<rootDir>/frontend/game"
    ],
    "transform": {
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.ts$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/frontend/game/$1",
      "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/frontend/tests/styleMock.js",
      "\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg)$": "<rootDir>/frontend/tests/fileMock.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!local-echo).+\\.js$"
    ]
  },
```

3. Typescript config, leveraging `baseUrl` combined with `paths`. Mine:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["frontend/game/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./frontend/**/*"
  ]
}
```

As far as I can tell, I have followed instructions exactly as indicated. After snooping around on github and stackoverflow, I've failed to discover what I am doing wrong, or whether there is some bug right now. I have experimented with adding `.vue` extension to the import, trying various combinations of path experiments (i.e. removing "frontend" from the `paths` object, placing and replacing pre- and post-path slashes, etc), and toggled settings such as `esModuleInterop`, to no avail.

**How can I get Jest to recognize my module aliases?**

EDIT: Fascinatingly, adding `//@ts-ignore` immediately before the import statement, causes this error to "go away," and jest then successfully imports the file.

EDIT2: The tsignore step made me suspicious of jest's ability to import a `.vue` file at all, so I explored that in [this issue on github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5298) as well as the [typescript recommendations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter#single-file-components) on `.vue` files. However, I already have a `vue-shims.d.ts` file identical to their recommendations. Just to experiment, I copied it all over the app, but no matter where I put it, there was no effect.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a `jest.config.js` with `modulesNameMapper` configuration matching your Webpack's.
Have a look at this easily digestible article: https://alexjover.com/blog/enhance-jest-configuration-with-module-aliases/